# Postgresql Error: must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

Before you guyz mark it as duplicate i tried several solutions given on this very same website but none of them worked.

My query

```
SELECT 
  temp_fk_settlements.sku, 
  temp_fk_settlements.order_item_id, 
  temp_fk_settlements.order_date, 
  sum(temp_fk_settlements.order_item_value), 
  sum(temp_fk_settlements.total_marketplace_fee), 
  sum(temp_fk_settlements.service_tax), 
  sum(temp_fk_settlements.settlement_value), 
  sum(temp_fk_settlements.commission), 
  sum(temp_fk_settlements.fixed_fee), 
  sum(temp_fk_settlements.shipping_fee), 
  sum(temp_fk_settlements.reverse_shipping_fee), 
  sum(temp_fk_settlements.invoice_amount)
FROM 
  temp_fk_returns, 
  temp_fk_settlements
WHERE
  temp_fk_settlements.order_item_id = temp_fk_returns.order_item_id and
  temp_fk_returns.return_type = 'customer_return'
GROUP BY
  temp_fk_settlements.order_item_id
```

My ERROR

```
ERROR:  column "temp_fk_settlements.sku" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or     
 be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2:   temp_fk_settlements.sku,
```

If i try to remove column temp_fk_settlements.sku it still gives me error on different column. i am stuck as none of the solution works.

i want to group the results based on order_item_id.

My table structure is

temp_fk_settlements:

```
Create table temp_fk_settlements(
    settlement_reference_no varchar(50),
    order_type char(20),
    fulfillment_type varchar(25),
    sku varchar(25),
    order_id varchar(25),
    order_item_id varchar(25),
    order_date date,
    dispatch_date date,
    delivery_date date,
    cancellation_date date,
    settlement_date date,
    order_status varchar(25),
    quantity integer,
    order_item_value integer,
    refund integer,
    protection_fund integer,
    total_marketplace_fee double precision,
    service_tax double precision,
    settlement_value double precision,
    commission_rate integer,
    commission double precision,
    fee_discount double precision,
    cancellation_fee double precision,
    fixed_fee integer,
    emi_fee double precision,
    total_weight float,
    shipping_fee double precision,
    reverse_shipping_fee double precision,
    shipping_zone char(15),
    token_of_apology double precision,
    pick_and_pack_fee double precision,
    storage_fee double precision,
    removal_fee double precision,
    invoice_id varchar,
    invoice_date date,
    invoice_amount integer,
    sub_category char(25),
    total_offer_amount double precision,
    my_offer_share double precision,
    flipkart_offer_share double precision
)
```

temp_fk_returns:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_fk_returns(
    return_id VARCHAR(25),
    order_id VARCHAR(25),
    order_item_id VARCHAR(25),
    product_id VARCHAR(25),
    title VARCHAR(100),
    sku VARCHAR(25),
    quantity INTEGER,
    total_price INTEGER,
    return_requested_on DATE,
    return_initiated_on DATE,
    return_tracking_id VARCHAR(25),
    status VARCHAR(25),
    reason VARCHAR(150),
    sub_reason VARCHAR(150),
    customer_comments VARCHAR,
    return_type VARCHAR(25)
)
```

Comment: It's both `sku` and `order_date`. Remove those two or wrap them in aggregate functions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you look at the logic of the query, you can see *why* this error occurs:

```
SELECT 
  temp_fk_settlements.sku, 
  temp_fk_settlements.order_item_id, 
  temp_fk_settlements.order_date
```

This says that for each row, you want the `sku`, `order_item_id`, and `order_date`.

```
GROUP BY
  temp_fk_settlements.order_item_id
```

This says you want one row for each unique `order_item_id`, no matter what else is different.

So, if there is more than `sku` or `order_date` for the same `order_item_id`, the database would have no way of knowing which of those values to give you. MySQL would just guess, but Postgres (like most other DB systems) tells you to change your query.

In this case, you probably know that every `order_item_id` corresponds to a single value of `sku` and `order_date`, so you can just add them all to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY
  temp_fk_settlements.sku, 
  temp_fk_settlements.order_item_id, 
  temp_fk_settlements.order_date
```

This says that you want one row for each unique combination of these three fields, so it is possible to view all the items in the combination.

Comment: Never understood this group by functionality so much better. Also my issue got solved by this.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

all not aggregated columns should be in GROUP BY... not just one of...

so either

```
group by 
  temp_fk_settlements.sku, 
  temp_fk_settlements.order_item_id, 
  temp_fk_settlements.order_date
```

or

```
select 
string_agg(temp_fk_settlements.sku,',') sku,
temp_fk_settlements.order_item_id, 
string_agg(order_date.order_date,',') order_date,
...etc
GROUP BY
  temp_fk_settlements.order_item_id
```

Comment: "not just one of", that depends on the primary key. When data is dependent on the primary key, you don't have to mention this in the group by clausule.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Ah, yes, I'd forgotten that. It was only added in 9.1, though, so it's possible that it's not supported on the version some people are running.